# Filling a form (caolan) with default values in node.js

Tags: forms, node.js, default

I am using caolan forms with node.js. My schema looks like:

```
var News = new Schema({
  name : String
, index: Number
});
```

My form has 3 news fields:

```
var news = forms.create({ news_1: fields.string({required: true}),
                          news_2: fields.string({required: true}),
                          news_3: fields.string({required: true})              
                       });
```

I now try to fill this form with default values which is where I need help. What am I doing wrong in the following code?

```
news.bind({news_1: "test1", news_2: "test2", news_3: "test3"});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can create form with this object

```
{ 
  news_1: fields.string({required: true, value : 'test1'}),
  news_2: fields.string({required: true, value : 'test2'}),
  news_3: fields.string({required: true, value : 'test3'})              
}
```